# Locate where a Component is being added

Tags: java, listener, stack-trace

The following is a very simple sample that adds a JButton and a JTextField to a Toolbar. The JButton is added via the line  **toolbar.add(button1);**  and the objective is to attempt to trace back to that specific line number and call.

```
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
    import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

    import javax.swing.*;

    public class ToolBarSample {
      public static void main(final String args[]) 
      {

        PropertyChangeListener propertyChangeListener = new PropertyChangeListener() 
        {
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent propertyChangeEvent) {
              String property = propertyChangeEvent.getPropertyName();
              System.out.println("Change... : " + property);
              if (property.equals("ancestor"))
              {
                  Thread.dumpStack();
              }
            }
          };

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JToolBar Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JToolBar toolbar = new JToolBar();
        toolbar.setRollover(true);

        JButton button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        button1.addPropertyChangeListener(propertyChangeListener);
        toolbar.add(button1);
        JTextField field1 = new JTextField ();
        toolbar.add(field1);

        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                field1.setText("Hello Wolrd");
            }
        });

        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        contentPane.add(toolbar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        contentPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10,10));
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }
    }
```

In this sample, a PropertyChange listener was added and it does fire 3 times with the following changes (border, defaultCapable, and ancestor).  Assuming ancestor is the one to track, a Thread.dumpStack() is executed when the property change is ancestor. Unfortunately, the stack returned doesn't lead me to the **toolbar.add(button1);**   line of code. It produces the following :

```
    Change... : border
    Change... : defaultCapable
    Change... : ancestor
    java.lang.Exception: Stack trace
        at java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Unknown Source)
        at ToolBarSample$1.propertyChange(ToolBarSample.java:19)
        at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(Unknown Source)
        at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
        at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JRootPane.addNotify(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.addNotify(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Frame.addNotify(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.show(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.show(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Unknown Source)
        at ToolBarSample.main(ToolBarSample.java:48)
```

In order to be able to trace back to the **toolbar.add(button1);** call, what other listener or code can be implemented?

Comment: What is the need for being able to do this? I suspect that there may be an XY Problem type question hiding here.